# Simple database search engine in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

i'm trying to make a simple search engine in AngularJS. I have an issue with the communication between my client and my server. I'm trying to follow the w3schools guide http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_sql.asp.

Here's home.php body :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">      
</script> 
</head>

<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
        <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("server.php")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.names = JSON.parse(response.data.records);});

});

</script>
```

and here's server.php :

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
error_reporting(2);

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mygaloo;charset=utf8', 'root',    ''); 
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM associations"); 
$outp = "";

while($donnees = $query->fetch()) 
{
    if ($outp != "") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"Name":"'  . $donnees["nom"] . '"}';
}

$outp ='{"records":['.$outp.']}';
$conn->close();


echo($outp);
?>
```

However, i'm gettin this error : **angular.js:12520SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0**, any idea ?

Comment: Make sure there is no error in `server.php` I reckon there is one..

Comment: I'm getting a white page with {{ x.Name }}.

Comment: Set `error_reporting(2);` and test..

Comment: `home.php:21 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`
However i'm not seeing any missing ) ? Also, `angular.js:4458Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A463)`

Comment: Your PHP is giving malformed output. Post output of GET request to the PHP script? Don't paste it into the comments, edit it into the answer! :-)

Comment: I corrected a number of syntax mistakes, but still a white page.
I also updated the error message.
How can i get the output of the GET request ?

Comment: Don't generate JSON by smashing strings together. It is extremely error prone. Use http://php.net/json_encode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got it. Arun Shinde answer was right, but the issue come from :

```
while($rs = $result->fetch(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
```

I'm using PDO so using MYSQLI here is not going to work, obviously.
So here the complete code that works.
home.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">     
    </script> 
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in names"> <td>{{ x }}</td> </tr>
    </table>
    </div>

    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {   
            $http.get("server.php")
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.names = response.data;
            }).then(function(response){
                console.log(response)
            })

    });
    </script>
</body>
```

server.php :

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mygaloo;charset=utf8', 'root', ''); 
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM associations"); 
$outp = [];
while($rs = $result->fetch()) {
    if ($outp != "")
    array_push($outp,$rs["nom"]);
}
$outp =json_encode($outp);
$conn = null;
echo($outp);
?>
```

Thanks a lot for your patience everybody !

Comment: Great. That's why i gave you all PHP code there. If you find the solution then try to accept answer; After all efforts for this only. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your angular code

```
<script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {   
                $http.get("server.php")
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.names = response.data;
                }).then(function(response){
                    console.log(response)
                })

        });
    </script>
```

and here is your PHP code. Hope it will help you.

```
<?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

  $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'root', ''); 
  $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM associations"); 
  $outp = [];
  while($rs = $result->fetch(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "")
    array_push($outp,$rs["nom"]);
  }
 $outp =json_encode($outp);
 $conn = null;
 echo($outp);
?>
```

Comment: The console.log return "undefined"

Comment: Ignore this. Are you getting any success in **$scope.names = response.data;**? Is error other than this. Here is your HTML to print it.                                                                                    **<tr ng-repeat="name in names">
     <td>{{ name }}</td>
    </tr>**

Comment: `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Comment: The error is coming from the back-end only. Your front-end is alright here. Push your values into the array and then echo that array using json_encode(). Already gave you working PHP code above.